# Ajax upload without progres bar

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I have a some code to ajax upload . its send request to my servlet and all works fine. But code contains a progress bar what i no need. Can u help me delete lines what i no need? 
Another question how to refresh DIV with my content after upload files? When i use this code to send parametrs to jsp page

```
$.post(
            "deletePoly.jsp",
            {ids:ch.toString()},
           function(per){
          $("#WRAPlist").load("listing.jsp");
            }
          );
```

Where i gonn put line

```
$("#WRAPlist").load("listing.jsp");
```

this is upload code

var req;

```
    function ajaxFunction()
    {
        var url = "Upload_Servlet";

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Non-IE browsers
        { 
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;

            try 
            {
                req.open("GET", url, true);
            } 
            catch (e) 
            {
                alert(e);
            }
            req.send(null);
        } 
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) // IE Browsers
        { 
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            if (req) 
            {
                req.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
                req.open("GET", url, true);
                req.send();
            }
        }
    }

    function processStateChange()
    {

         *  State   Description
         *  0       The request is not initialized
         *  1       The request has been set up
         *  2       The request has been sent
         *  3       The request is in process
         *  4       The request is complete

        if (req.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (req.status == 200) // OK response
            {
                var xml = req.responseXML;

                // No need to iterate since there will only be one set of lines
                var isNotFinished = xml.getElementsByTagName("finished")[0];
                var myBytesRead = xml.getElementsByTagName("bytes_read")[0];
                var myContentLength = xml.getElementsByTagName("content_length")[0];
                var myPercent = xml.getElementsByTagName("percent_complete")[0];

                // Check to see if it's even started yet
                if ((isNotFinished == null) && (myPercent == null))
                {
                    document.getElementById("initializing").style.visibility = "visible";

                    // Sleep then call the function again
                    window.setTimeout("ajaxFunction();", 100);
                }
                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById("initializing").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("progressBarTable").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("percentCompleteTable").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("bytesRead").style.visibility = "visible";

                    myBytesRead = myBytesRead.firstChild.data;
                    myContentLength = myContentLength.firstChild.data;

                    if (myPercent != null) // It's started, get the status of the upload
                    {
                        myPercent = myPercent.firstChild.data;

                        document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = myPercent + "%";
                        document.getElementById("bytesRead").innerHTML = myBytesRead + " of " + 
                            myContentLength + " bytes read";
                        document.getElementById("percentComplete").innerHTML = myPercent + "%";

                        // Sleep then call the function again
                        window.setTimeout("ajaxFunction();", 100);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("bytesRead").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = "100%";
                        document.getElementById("percentComplete").innerHTML = "Done!";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert(req.statusText);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these line of codes then it will not display progressbar..

```
document.getElementById("initializing").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("progressBarTable").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("percentCompleteTable").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("bytesRead").style.visibility = "visible";

myBytesRead = myBytesRead.firstChild.data;
myContentLength = myContentLength.firstChild.data;

if (myPercent != null) // It's started, get the status of the upload
{
   myPercent = myPercent.firstChild.data;
   document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = myPercent + "%";
   document.getElementById("bytesRead").innerHTML = myBytesRead + " of " + 
                            myContentLength + " bytes read";
   document.getElementById("percentComplete").innerHTML = myPercent + "%";

   // Sleep then call the function again
   window.setTimeout("ajaxFunction();", 100);
   }
   else
   {
     document.getElementById("bytesRead").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = "100%";
     document.getElementById("percentComplete").innerHTML = "Done!";
   }
```

Comment: I want to delete progress bar couse its showing there. http://s42.radikal.ru/i097/1206/42/aa4b40432b3e.jpg

Comment: Okey i corrected css and put progress bar where i want. But anyway how to refresh content DIV?

Comment: for what you need to refresh ?

Comment: After upload file his name gonna show in DIV. Its for dont refresh whole page.

Comment: you can set the innerhtml of a div as document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = 'name of a file';

Comment: atlast you jsp file also going to convert to html file and the syntax is pure html code..

Comment: and where i gonna put this? I try do document.getElementById("percentComplete").innerHTML = "Done!"; $("#WRAPlist").load("listing.jsp");
 In fireBug see that listing.jsp loaded but new file dont show in DIV. Its mean that listing.jsp was loaded faster that servlet complete his work?

Comment: Oh sorry it s just was a bug. After redeploy all forks fine. Tnx for your help.

Comment: ARRRRR THIS AJAX. Icant understand this. I upload file first time, after upload my jsp page with content was loaded but new file not showing in DIV. But if i delete this file and upload this again it showing. WHY?

Comment: you can see the content of the percentComplete div in page source. one more thing if you are using firefox you can see the error console by pressing ctrl + shift + j it will show you error if any ..

Comment: I found. setTimeout(function(pt){$('#WRAPlist').load('listing.jsp')}, 5000); in this case all fine. DIV loaded after servlet works. But Timeout its bad solution. How to get something from servlet when his work complete?

Comment: My english is terrible. ready() execute code after whole page is loaded? Im right?